# Pandas - What is the argument given to functions in agg() when applied to a DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe 'reviews' that has attributes 'variety' and 'price'. I want to list the maximum and minimum price for each variety. The following works

```
reviews.groupby('variety').price.agg([max, min])
```

but this does not

```
reviews.groupby('variety').agg([ lambda df: df.price.max(), lambda df: df.price.min() ])
```

because it says that the datatype Series does not have attribute "price". I was expecting a data frame to be passed into the lambda functions. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

[`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) works at the Series level (unlike [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)).

If you want to specify columns on which to apply the aggregation function(s), you have several options:

Slicing:

```
reviews.groupby('variety')['price'].agg(['max', 'min'])

# or using lambdas
reviews.groupby('variety')['price'].agg([lambda s: s.max(), lambda : s.min()])
```

Using a dictionary:

```
reviews.groupby('variety').agg({'price': ['max' 'min']})
```

For further information see [`groupby.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)